# Php Mysql insert query doesnt work under if condition or direct

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql insert query is not insert under condition. Its not giving any kind of error. But update query is working. please help

```
//this query gets the status of reward system if its enabled
$reward =   mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("
            select * from on_off where ename = 'reward' and status = 1
            "));
            $trueN  =   $reward['status'];

//this query gets the info if member already exist
// if member record already exist then it will update otherwise it will insert
$rewardz    =   mysql_query("
            select * from rewards where mem_id = 1
            ");
            $trueM  =   mysql_num_rows($rewardz);

if ($trueN == 1 && $trueM == 1){

mysql_query("
update rewards
set amount = 12
where mem_id = 1
");

}elseif ($trueN == 1 && $trueM == 0){

$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `rewards` (`amount`, `mem_id`)
VALUES (1, 1)");

}
```

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Can you do some proper code indentation? It'll make things easier to read and you might see the problem.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working.
Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your queries.

Comment: first you are using mysql, second you are not checking error, third if query does not work, that's simply means there is some thing wrong in the query, check your query

Comment: its not giving any kind of error

Answer (score 0):

you need to use mysqli_multi_query() to perform multiple queries. read more on this link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

Comment: you want him to run multiple query, you know it risky as hell,